# RequestHandler from AWS returns Null pointer

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Person, String> {

private static AmazonDynamoDB client;
private static Item item;

// TODO: implement your handler
@Override
public String handleRequest(Person input, Context context) {
    context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input.toString());

    try {
        //initialize the connection
        init();

        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);

        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("Person");

        item = table.getItem("PersonID", input.getPersonID());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return item.toJSON();
}
}
```

Hello, I am trying to make this example work in order to understand in more depth the AWS lambda functionality. The person object has only one field the id as a variable with a constructor, a getter and a setter.
The invoke requet that i sent is a json in this form:

```
{
 "PersonID": 1
}
```

My problem occurs when i run it(Run function on AWS lambda), the person input does not take the value from the request json and it is null, so it collapses(null pointer exception). Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Are you positive the json is being passed? Have you tried just operating on a String instead of a Person as a test?

Comment: I havent tested with a string to be honest. How can i be positive that is being passed as you said?

Comment: You could try changing the `input` in your handler from a Person to a String. I'm wondering if the problem is with the delivery of the POST body or with the deserialization of it to a Person.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is related to POJO/JavaBean naming conventions. Instead of PersonID in your event JSON, try personID with getter method getPersonID(). That's assuming that it allows ID and doesn't require you to call it Id.

Comment: @jarmod2 Your idea was correct by following the naming conventions, serialization happened at once without null pointer. Thanks for this.

Comment: @Giota - Amazing. I found a resolution to my issue in this post. I was struggling with the same issue. It would be good if you could post an answer to this post and accept it